# NSRegularExpression in backward direction?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, regex, nsregularexpression

I have a knowledge about `NSBackwardSearch` for searching the string in backward direction.

My question, Can i do the same backward direction search through `NSRegularExpression`.

If it is, Please share your knowledge?

Comment: Do you want to find the last match or read the string backwards when searching?

Comment: My aim is to find the last match. But if it is a long string, it is not optimal find all occurrences, then get the result by occurrence[occurrence.length-1].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no notion of a backwards search with NSRegularExpression, you will need to use capture groups and find the last occurrence. It is mentioned nowhere in the [class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

If you had reason to believe the match would be in the latter part of a very large string, you could search a substring of that large string first, but personally I would not try to pre-optimize my code this way.

Answer (score 1):

You can reverse your enumerator you use on the result array of your regular expression:

```
NSString *regExPattern = @"<strong>.*?</strong>";
NSError *error = nil;
static NSRegularExpression *regex = nil;
regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:regExPattern
                                                      options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive | NSRegularExpressionDotMatchesLineSeparators
                                                        error:&error];

NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:HTMLString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, HTMLString.length)];

for (NSTextCheckingResult *result in [matches reverseObjectEnumerator] /*HERE'S THE MAGIC*/)
{
    //Do something here
}
```